# Put one div after another

Tags: html, css

I want to set two divs like the following.
http://snag.gy/ynuiY.jpg

This is my HTML code

```
<div id="topbar">
This is a top bar
</div>

<div id="wrapper"> 
wrapper
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#wrapper{
    z-index:2;
    marign-top: 30px;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
    left:auto ;
    right:auto ;
    margin: auto;

}

#topbar{
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    color:#FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But the output is like following. (no wrapper)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXuWD.jpg

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You have a type error `marign-top: 30px;` should be `margin-top: 30px;`

Comment: What is `position:absolute;` doing there?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hr1007n4/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D - Thanks Paulie. But the problem is still there.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I want to display that div without any white spaces in the top

Comment: @AndrewMatthew - I want to display topbar div without any white spaces in the top

Comment: You can do that by making the margin and padding of the body `0`. I think that's a better approach than using `position: absolute` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your `#wrapper` margin to padding

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/612ukLxn/)

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to set `#topbar` position to `relative`:

```
#topbar{
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    position:relative;/*Change to relative*/
    color:#FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also is `margin-top` no `marign-top`

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1dy7zzcz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:
http://jsfiddle.net/ht8k40tr/

The problem is due to the order in which you're setting the margins.

Currently you're setting the top margin to be 30px, but then you're resetting that by setting all margins to auto, a simpler way to do this is just to set the margin as follows `margin: 30px auto` which sets the top margin to 30px, and the remaining margins to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "margin-top: 30px;" to "padding-top: 30px;"

```
#wrapper {
    padding-top: 30px;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
    left:auto ;
    right:auto ;
    margin: auto;
}
```